# How to access a getter from an object of a LinkedList

Tags: java, android, object, getter

Following Scenario:
Classes:

**GamePlayScene**   (Game logic and collision detection)
**Obstacle**        (has the Rect getObstacleBounds() method to return Bounds)
**ObstacleManager** (has the LinkedList of obstacle objects)

I want to access the Boundaries (an android.Rect) of an obstacle. All obstacles will be stored into a LinkedList.

Now in the running game I want to access the getObstacleBounds() method in my **GameplayScene Class** but the problem is that I can't access the obstacle object directly but I obviously have to cycle through all my Objects in the LinkedList in my ObstacleManager.

Due to that I thought I have to also implement a Rect getObstacleBounds() in my Obstacle Manager, from where I cycle through every obstacle in my List and return that Rect.

Is this the right way to do so? I am fairly new to accessing objects and their methods in a LinkedList

If not: How would I implement access to such methods?

Here is my idea what I thought cold work / be the right way.
(Not compilable, more or less pseudo code)

***GameplayScene.java***

```
private ObstacleManager obstacleManager;

public GameplayScene() {

  obstacleManager = new ObstacleManager();
  obstacleManager.addObstacle(new Obstacle(...));
}

public void hitDetection() {
//get the Boundaries of obstacle(s) for collision detection
}
```

***Obstacle.java***

```
//...
public Rect getObstacleBounds() {
   return obstacleBounds;
}
```

***ObstacleManager.java***

```
LinkedList<Obstacle> obstacles = new LinkedList<>();

public void update() { //example method 
    for (Obstacle o : obstacles){
        o.update();
    }
}

public Rect getObjectBounds() {
   return ...
   //how do I cycle through my objects and return each Bounds Rect?
}
```

Comment: just iterate through list and get bound's the way you are using update method!.what is the problem you are facing?

Comment: I think my problem is the lack of syntax knowledge with LinkedLists... 
What I tried is the following:

public Rect getObstacleBounds() {

for (Obstacle o : obstacles) {
      o.getObstacleBounds();
   }
return ...?
}

This is obviously not compilable and my second problem is how to access this from my GameplayScene.

I would be very happy about a code example by you. Thanks for the help, much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, depends of what you want to do in `hitDetection`

**If you just want to check if a hit happened**

In this case, you can just receive the list of  `Rect` and check if any hit happened

GameplayScene.java

```
public void hitDetection() {
    ArrayList<Rect> listOfBounds = obstacleManager.getObstacleBounds();
    for(Rect bound : listOfBounds) {
        // Do you stuff
        // Note the here, you are receiving a list of Rects only.
        // So, you can only check if a hit happened.. but you can't update the Obstacles because here, you don't have access to them.
        // Nothing stops you of receiving the whole list of items if you want to(like the reference of ObstacleManager.obstacles).
    }
}
```

ObstacleManager.java

```
    public ArrayList<Rect> getObjectBounds() {
        // You can also return just an array.. like Rect[] listToReturn etc
        ArrayList<Rect> listToReturn = new ArrayList(obstacles.size());
        for (Obstacle item : obstacles) {
            listToReturn.add(item.getObjectBounds);
        }
        return listToReturn;
    }
```

**If you need to update some info on the Obstacle that was hit**

In this case, you can transfer the hitDetection logic to you ObstacleManager (I'm assuming you check coordinates X and Y to check if obstacle was hit):

GameplayScene.java

```
public void hitDetection(int touchX, int touchY) {
    Obstacle objectHit = obstacleManager.getObstacleTouched(int touchX, int touchY);
    if (objectHit != null) {
        objectHit.doStuffAlpha();
        objectHit.doStuffBeta();
    } else {
        // No obstacle was hit.. Nothing to do
    }
}
```

ObstacleManager.java

```
public Obstacle getObstacleTouched(int touchX, int touchY) {
    Obstacle obstacleToReturn = null;
    for (Obstacle item : obstacles) {
        if(item.wasHit(touchX, touchY) {
            obstacleToReturn = item;
            break;
        }
    }
    return listToReturn;
}
```

There are several ways to achieve what you want. Some better than others etcIn the end, depends of what you want to do exactly.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I needed. I am not very new to Java but haven't explored stuff like LinkedLists  and other form of staples, lists or any type of array like datatype. Everything I did in the Game was manageable with primitives and basic if's and getters and setters.